# How can find the slope of a GLM logit model?

Tags: r, logit, model

I've created a logit model using GLM and I´d like to get the slope of the independent variables.

I've read that using `coef()` in R it´s possible to do it, but the only thing I have back is the coefficients that I already have using `summary()`.

I'm trying to get the slope at mean, like the one that is given when we use Gretl.

Comment: Are you after $\frac{\partial \hat{p}}{\partial x}$ at $x=\bar x$? Or the slope of the linear predictor?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, I think it would be the slope of the linear predictor.

Comment: That's just the coefficient itself.

Comment: @Glen_b, how can I do that calculation of the derivative in R, I´m really new to this all, and most of the job I´m doing in R is using Rattle.

Comment: You would do the derivative algebraically and then it will be a simple calculation from the coefficient, I'm just trying to figure out *which* possible answer you wanted rather than spend time giving an answer you don't want. That first thing would be [this slope](http://i.imgur.com/5ncu6LO.png). That slope is a quarter of the coefficient.

Comment: How does the slope you mention in Gretl relate to the coefficient? Do you have a numeric example (just the two values would do)?

Comment: Thanks @glen_b, I'll get an example to show what I'm asking. As fas as I know, the slope coefficient will help to understand the inclination of the especific variable according to the sigmoid created by the logit model, right?

Comment: If you're after the slope of the sigmoid at the steepest point (see my linked diagram in the previous comment), the relationship is as I stated there. It measures the fastest rate of increase in $P(Y=1)$ against that $x$ variable.